# How to add dynamic control to datagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am little bit confused here i want some code here for this one or control
here is my requirement
I have datagridview like this 
[image]

Now when i add 7 to total taka then another one will be shown like this one
[image]

now real scenario when i add value 3 to total taka then in second gridview it should be shown like this

```
Srno  Meters
1     null
2     null
3     null
```

same should be repeated adding new rows to first datagridview how would i achieve this?

Comment: don't understand your requirement, you should rephrase your problem, it's not really clear.

Comment: ok doing it @king kong

Comment: why adding `7` the second grid doesn't show with `7` entries like as when adding `3`? Is that some kind of `key number`? I mean only entering `7` will show the second grid, otherwise the second grid won't be shown?

Comment: Use punctuation. Your question is still extremely unclear. Do you have two grids where one is supposed to summarize the other? I can't tell at all.

Comment: @exactly king kong it is i am sorry i can't give clear question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding code to a `CellEndEdit` event handler, then you can show an already created hidden `DataGridView` as the second one or you can also create that `DataGridView` on the fly. It's up to you. I prefer to show that `DataGridView` and initialize the number of rows. Here is the code helping you understand the idea:

```
//First you have to layout 2 DataGridViews at design time and set the Visible of the second 
//DataGridView to false
//Your dataGridView2 should also have 2 columns added at design time as shown
//in your second picture.
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
  //Suppose the column with header Total kaka has name TotalKaka
  if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "TotalKaka") {
      int i;
      if (int.TryParse(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), out i))
      {
          dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
          dataGridView2.Rows.Add(i);
          for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
             dataGridView2[0, j].Value = j + 1;
          dataGridView2.Show();
          dataGridView2.CurrentCell = dataGridView2[1, 0];
          dataGridView2.Focus();          
      }
  }
}
//you should have some Submit button to submit the values entered into the second
//dataGridView, we should process something and surely hide the dataGridView2
private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    dataGridView2.Hide();
    //other code to process your data
    //....
}
```

**NOTE**: This answers to your actual requirement in this question, I guess you may have more problems such as ***How to process the data entered in dataGridView2***? ***How to show the dataGridView2 in another form?*** ... such problems do exist and I think you should ask for the solution in other questions, don't try asking for solving them right in this question.

Comment: Thanks for reply but this is for the one row in gridview1 but i have to do for the each row if i would have only 1 row in gridview1 then this code will work but for all will not work

Comment: @dholakiyaankit why do you think this works only for 1 row in `gridview1`? It works for every row in that grid, looks like you haven't even tried it yet?

Comment: Ok i am trying then i am replying you

Comment: Thanks for the reply actually i have changed my login i add dynamic columns to first column so that i don't have to use second one